# How to find the average and median values of the column 'Total Traded Quantity' for each of the types of 'Trend'

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

```
df_trend = df.groupby(["Trend"])
average_trades = df_trend["Total Traded Quantity"].mean()
print("The average traded quantity is: ", average_trades)

>>The average traded quantity is:  Trend
Slight or No Change    1.635627e+06
Name: Total Traded Quantity, dtype: float64
```

But I have 9 types of trends in `Trend` column, although I get only one type here in the output. How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby(df.Trend).mean()['Total Traded Quantity']
df.groupby(df.Trend).median()['Total Traded Quantity']
```

or

```
df_trend_average = df.groupby(df.Trend).mean()
df_trend_median = df.groupby(df.Trend).median()
```